# Tutorial for integrating three 20 in xcode 4.0.2 iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
This may be a simple question,but i cant figure out the correct way.

I my project i want to integrate three 20 and i found a tutorial
`https://github.com/facebook/three20/`.

But i think this is for older version of xcode.
```

Many of the sections specified in this tutorial is not found in my xcode project.

```
Is there any tutorial available for xcode 4.0.2 in tegrating three 20.

Can anybody help me please.

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this visual explanation of adding three20 framework in your X-code project:

http://chepri.com/visual-guide-manually-adding-three20-xcode-4-project/

Comment: Link-rot means that generally link-only answers are poorly received. It is generally better to summarise how something might apply, or, if it really *is* just a link, add it as a comment.

Comment: Ok Marc Gravell remember it for future.